# AngularJS directive - pros and cons of passing in an options object vs separate attributes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I am creating a directive for a scatter chart that should have a whole set of configurable attributes.
To the best of my knowledge, I can either set these up individual scope attributes:

```
directive('scatterChart', ['$http', function($http){
 scope: {
   data: "=?",
   selected : "=?",
   indicatorX : "=?",
   indicatorY : "=?",
   indicatorSize : "=?"
 }
```

Or pass an object with options:

```
directive('scatterChart', ['$http', function($http){
 scope: {
   model: "=?",
 }
```

In the latter case I would not have to go back and tweak my markup, this would be sufficient:

```
<div class="scatter-chart" model="scatter.options">
```

And inside my directive it would be sufficient to watch the object to trigger a re-render:

```
scope.$watch('model', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    render();
}, true);
```

So, which approach should I adopt and why?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple attributes may be a good solution if you wanted to override one or two parameters. Personally I like the object "pattern" as it keeps everything contained and I can update the model from the controller without touching my HTML.

Depends on how you want to update the model variables as well. Are you going through controller/scope methods or updating via .attr() (or other dom manipulation framework)?  Comes down to your needs, but I think using an object is best for matainence.